# Как добавить сертификат к Post запросу, библиотека xNet, C#, ЭЦП, *.cer

Tags: c#, post, сертификат, xnet, цифровая-подпись

Приветствую! Работаю с библиотекой xNet. Нужно отправить POST запрос, а именно подписать его сертификатом, полученным от администрации сервера. Как это сделать? Реально ли это реализовать через xNet?

> ## Электронно-Цифровая Подпись (далее – ЭЦП)
>
> Ассиметричные ключи создаются каждой из сторон самостоятельно. Затем выполняется обмен открытыми ключами для проверки подписи запроса. Запросы и ответы подписываются секретным ключом. Корректность подписи проверяется принимающей стороной открытым ключом.
>
> ## Формирование подписи запроса
>
> Для формирования ключей используется протокол X.509.
>
> Для формирования подписи исходящего запроса необходимо:
>
> - Используемый при формировании ЭЦП алгоритм RSA + SHA1    http://www.w3.org/PICS/DSig/RSA-SHA1_1_0.html
> - Подписывается содержимое исходящего сообщения заключенное между тегами  и    исключая сами теги.
> - Полученное значение подписи помещается в тег sig в формате HEX.

Заранее благодарю, не требую полного кода, мне нужно именно понимание того, что они хотят видеть и как это реализовать)

Comment: `.cer` файл содержит только сертификат (без приватного ключа). Таким сертификатом невозможно получить цифровую подпись. Я не знаю, что такое xNet, но средства для RSA подписи в C# есть.

Comment: @Zergatul благодарю!) В общем идею я уловил, далее скорее всего сам разберусь)